# Implementing an if and else statement for a URL in ajax

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I have a form with dropdown values, etc which allows our end users to upload documents to our server. Is it possible to implement an if and else statement to switch the .ajax URL depending on a value selected on the form? The issue is, we want to keep specific documents in a separate directory entirely meaning we have 2 repos.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/ABC/REPO_1/",
       type: "POST"..
```

I would like to implement an if and else to swap the directories depending on the value selected from my form on the front end.

example:

```
if(htmldirectory == 'Main Documents', "/ABC/REPO_1/", "/ABC/REPO_2/")
```

Hoping this makes sense, if not please let me know where I can clarify. Much thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

1- use a variable for url:

```
let selection = $('foo option:selected').val()

if(selection == 'Main Documents')
   url_repo = '/ABC/REPO_1/'
else
   url_repo = '/ABC/REPO_2/'

$.ajax({
   url: url_repo,
   type: "POST"..
```

2- one line:

```
$.ajax({
       url: ($('foo option:selected').val()=='Main Documents') : "/ABC/REPO_1/" ? "/ABC/REPO_2/" ,
       type: "POST"..
```

Comment: Thank you Milad. I do have it set up based on your #1 example, but I don't think the if and else is working. It looks like its only going into REPO_1 regardless of the condition for some reason.